# Scope And Relationship on Same Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table called `payments` which contains a field called `Vendor ZIP`.

I have a table called `201502_postcodes` and my "join" in this case is the `postcode` field in this table.

How do I return field values in this `201502_postcodes` table using Eloquent?

My Models are;

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Payment extends Model {

public function postcodeExtract()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PostcodeExtract', 'postcode', 'Vendor ZIP');
}
```

_

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PostcodeExtract extends Model {

protected $connection = 'postcodes';

public function scopeFromTable($query, $tableName) 
{
    return $query->from($tableName);
}

public function payment()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Payment', 'Vendor ZIP', 'postcode');
}
```

So, I have a `scope` on this model because the `201502` part of my table name is a variable (in that, a new one comes in every quarter).

In my controller... I have no idea what to put. I don't know how to get both scope and relationship to work. How can I write a query that will take a postcode/zip and output one of the fields from the (do I refer to them as "methods"?) postcode extract table?

It is not a duplicate of this question [Laravel 4: Dynamic table names using setTable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044577/laravel-4-dynamic-table-names-using-settable) because relationships are not involved or discussed on that question.

--- UPDATE ---

If I am to use `getTable` - would it go something like this...

```
class PostcodeExtract {

  public function setTableByDate($selected_tablename)
  {
    $this->table = $selected_tablename;

    // Return $this for method chaining
    return $this;
  }

  public function getTable()
  {
    if (isset($this->table))
        $this->setTableByDate($this->table);

    return $this->table;
  }
}
```

And then I would use it in my controller like;

```
$selected_tablename = 201502_postcode //created by some other controller
$postcode_extract = new PostcodeExtract;
$data = $postcode_extract->setTableByDate($selected_tablename)->get()->toArray();
```

The `Carbon` stuff isn't really relevant. I have a lookup to get those tablenames the fact the prefix with a date like value shouldn't mean it's treated like a date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4: Dynamic table names using setTable()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044577/laravel-4-dynamic-table-names-using-settable)

Comment: @user3158900 It's not.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here.

**scopeFromTable() is redundant**

Laravel employs magic methods to handle calls to undefined methods. Calling from() on the model will actually call from() on the models internal Query object (*assuming you didn't define a method called 'from' on the model itself*). It's worth reading the [__call and __callStatic](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3360) methods on the Model class.

**relationships use getTable()**

Another aspect of the Laravel is the concept of **convention over configuration**. This basically means that the framework assumes some things so that you don't have to define every detail. In regards to table naming convention, it will naturally use a table name derived from the class name.

```
// Uses table 'foos'
class Foo {}
```

There are a few ways to change this behavior. First, you can define a 'table' data member like this.

```
class Foo {
    protected $table = 'bars';
}
```

If you need a more dynamic behavior, then you can redefine the getTable method.

```
class Foo {
    public function getTable()
    {
        // return your special table name based on today's date
    }
}
```

Ultimately the models and their relationships refer to [getTable](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1924) to figure out what the table names should be.

**your use cases**

If you only ever need to query the *current* table, then I would suggest redefining getTable.

If you need to query both *current* and *past* tables, then I suggest pairing a new method along side redefining getTable

```
class Foo {
    public function setTableByDate(\DateTime $date)
    {
        $this->table = // generate table name from $date

        // Return $this for method chaining
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTable()
    {
        if (isset($this->table))
            $this->setTableByDate(\Carbon\Carbon::now());

        return $this->table;
    }
}
```

With this in place, you don't have to worry about the table name in your controller or anywhere else unless you need to query past records.

**setting the table by date per user**

$foos = Foo::setTableByDate($user->some_date)->where(...)->get();

Comment: That date prefix (ie, the table that is used) is defined by the user - so it won't always be the latest date. So what should my controller code look like?

Comment: I am still quite new to OOP... but if I use getTable - isn't that a getter?? Wouldn't I need something like setTable to change my table name?

Comment: Yes and no. The model and relationships call getTable. So if you redefine getTable within your model, then you effect all the related database calls. You'll need to gain an understanding of _inheritance_ in OOP.

Comment: @ColinJames I think I follow.. Does my UPDATE in Original post make sense?

Comment: It seems to work quite well having tested it :) I still haven't got an answer for getting the relationships to work though. But it should be easier now that I'm using getTable(). So I will keep this open for now and come back if I find a solution.

Comment: You could just use from() instead of the new method. The purpose of that was to put the code to generate the table name in one place rather